# Error in setting Trigger property in Xaml file

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am facing the following Error in setting Trigger property for button click event: The Property 'TargetType' is required to create a 'Xamarin.Forms.Trigger' object.

My code in Xaml file is:

```
<Style x:Key="BtnTriggers" TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                <Setter Property = "Foreground" Value="Green"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this:

You have missed `TargetType="Button"` inside `<Trigger>`

```
<Style x:Key="BtnTriggers" TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger TargetType="Button" Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                <Setter Property = "Foreground" Value="Green"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```